# Redirect all pages to new domain, but specific URLS to specific page on new domain

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to set up a redirect that for some reason is missing the folder when it redirects and does not go to the new URL, homepage works fine.

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 / https://www.newdomain.com
Redirect 301 /retail-signage.html /projects/retail-signage/
```

Any of the above go to www.newdomain.com/retail-signage.html but it should go to www.newdomain.com//projects/retail-signage/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Redirect` with `mod_rewrite` rules as they both are 2 different modules.

You may use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteEngine ^retail-signage\.html$ /projects/retail-signage/ [L,NC,R=301]
```